# Difference between component and container in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What is the difference between component and container in react redux?

Comment: containers are aware of the store and transmit state props to the components. The only goal of components is to render html, ideally components are stateless then it' will be easier write unit tests

Answer (score 205, accepted):

`Component` is part of the React API. A Component is a class or function that describes part of a React UI.

*Container* is an informal term for a React component that is `connect`-ed to a redux store. Containers receive Redux state updates and `dispatch` actions, and they usually don't render DOM elements; they delegate rendering to *presentational* child components.

For more detail read [presentational vs container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by Dan Abramov.

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll see that Dan Abromov has backed away from this pattern.  That said, I'm still considering the implications of the comment by @olivier-boisse regarding testing.

Comment: seems like a useful separation of concerns approach. Components are just presentation (like View) and containers are functionality and data getters to pass to components (like back end, repository, Model, etc)

Answer (score 15):

**Components**

Components let you split the UI into independent, reusable pieces, and think about each piece in isolation. They are sometimes called "presentational components" and the main concern is **how things look**

**Containers**

Containers are just like components without UI and Containers are concerned with **how things work.**. It mainly talks to the redux store for getting and updating the data

see the table comparison from Redux doc

[image]

Detailed explanation https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components

Answer (score 10):

Component which is responsible for fetching  data and displaying is called smart or container components. Data can be come from redux, any network call or third party subscription.

Dumb/presentational components are those which are responsible for presenting view based on props received.

Good article with example here

https://www.cronj.com/blog/difference-container-component-react-js/

Comment: Data coming from **props** is not specific for container. It  is common for all components.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Agreed. Props is props for all.

Answer (score 6):

React has two main components first is smart component(containers) and second is dumb(presentation component). Containers are very similar to components, the only difference is that containers are aware of application state. If part of your webpage is only used for displaying data (dumb) then make it a component. If you need it to be smart and aware of the state (whenever data changes) in the application then make it a container.

Answer (score 5):

The components construct a piace of the view, so it should render DOM elements, put content on the screen.

The containers participate in the data elaboration, so it should "talk" with redux, because it will need to modify the state. So, you should include **connect** (react-redux) what it makes the connection, and the functions **mapStateToProps** and **mapDispatchToProps** :

```
.
.
.
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class myContainer extends Component {
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // You return what it will show up as props of myContainer
  return {
    property: this.state.property
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  // Whenever property is called, it should be passed to all reducers
  return bindActionCreators({ property: property }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myContainer);
```

Answer (score 2):

They're both components; containers are functional, so they do not render any html on their own, and then you also have presentational components, where you write the actual html.  The purpose of the container is to map the state and dispatch to props for the presentational component.

Further reading: [Link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Answer (score 1):

React, Redux are independent libraries.

React provides you with a framework for creating HTML documents. Components are in a way representing a particular part of the document. Methods associated with a component can then manipulated the very particular part of the document.

Redux is a framework which prescribes to a specific philosphy for storing and managing data in JS environments. It a one big JS object with certain methods defined, best use case comes in the form of state management of a web app.

Since React prescribes that all the data should flow down from root to leaves, it becomes tedious to main all the props, defining props in components and then passing props to certain props to children. It also makes the entire application state vulnerable.

React Redux offers a clean solution, where it directly connects you to the Redux store, by simply wrapping the connected component around another React Component( your `Container`). Since in your implementaion, your implementation you already defined which piece of the entire application state you require. So `connect` takes that data out of store and passes it as props to the component it wrapping itself arround.

Consider this simple example:

```
 class Person extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   this.name = this.props.name;
   this.type = this.props.type;
  }

  render() {
     return <p> My name is {this.name}. I am a doctor { this.type } </p>
  }
}

 const connect = InnerComponent => { 

   class A extends Component{
     render() {
        return <InnerComponent {...this.props} type="Doctor"/>
     }
   } 
   A.displayName = `Connect(${InnerComponent.displayName})`
   return A
 }
```

`connect` function passes a prop `type`.

This way a connect acts as container for the Person component.